# Fixing MATLAB Bug -- Not all graphs displaying when publishing

Tags: matlab, plot, report, publish

I'm writing some simple code in MATLAB and for some reason it's only displaying the last graph in the HTML and/or pdf file when I publish it. Does anyone know how/why this can happen? stackoverflow isn't letting me post my code so any suggestions about common causes of this bug would be appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Would it be that MATLAB overwrites the content of the current figure? Have you tried creating a new figure with the `figure` command? It also sets the newly created figure to be the current figure.

Comment: How is stackoverflow not letting you post code? Is it simply too long? In that case, please make a short example that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using SNAPNOW ? http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/snapnow.html

Comment: Hi everyone, just for clarification I didn't started putting the command figure() over all of my graphs and the problem stopped happening. Apparently this is really common and it's considered good form to put it there anyways.